# Indecomposable Lie algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, matrix-decomposition

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $k$ of characteristic zero. Suppose that $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$, and suppose that the representation ad$:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{gl}(\mathfrak{g})$ is faithful, i.e. $\mathfrak{g}$ has trivial centre.

Recall that for all $x\in\mathfrak{g}$, $x=x_s+x_n$ for some commuting $x_s,x_n\in\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ such that ad$(x_s)$ is diagonalisable, ad$(x_n)$ is nilpotent, and both act as derivations on $\mathfrak{g}$. This is the *Jordan decomposition* for $x$. We say that $\mathfrak{g}$ is *decomposable* if $x_s$ and $x_n$ both lie in $\mathfrak{g}$ for all $x\in\mathfrak{g}$.

It is true that if $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple, then $\mathfrak{g}$ is always decomposable, using the fact that all derivations of $\mathfrak{g}$ are of the form ad$(y)$ for some $y\in\mathfrak{g}$, but I don't think this holds in general for solvable Lie algebras.

My question is, does anyone know of any examples of solvable Lie algebras with trivial centre that are *not* decomposable? Or if not, then does anyone know a proof that they always are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lie algebra $L$ over a field of characteristic zero has an abstract Jordan-Chevalley decomposition if and only if $L$ is perfect. Hence solvable Lie algebras do not have such a decomposition.

Reference: [Jordan-Chevalley decomposition](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2011-139-11/S0002-9939-2011-10827-X/S0002-9939-2011-10827-X.pdf).

Example: Let $L$ be the non-abelian Lie algebra of dimension $2$, with basis $x,y$ and bracket $[x,y]=x$.

If we are not assuming $[x_s,x_n]=0$ for the Jodan decomposition, then we have the following result:

*Theorem:* Let $L$ be a solvable Lie algebra of matrices, let $A ∈ L$ and assume that $A = S + N$ with $S, N ∈ L$, where $S$ is semisimple, $N$ is nilpotent (we are not assuming $[S, N ] = 0$). Then the semisimple and nilpotent summands of the JCD of $A$ belong to $L$.

Reference: [This article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.09096.pdf).

Comment: You're right! I hadn't considered this - I realise that I was using the wrong decomposition. Instead I should consider $\mathfrak{g}$ embedded as a subalgebra of upper triangular matrices using Lie's theorem, in which case there is a decomposition into semisimple and nilpotent parts, these do not commute, and using the Theorem you stated, we see that these both lie in the algebra. Thanks!